# Apply android Picasso library to Sqlite decodeByteArray image

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I'm using Sqlite to save images and this is the code I use to bring they back to a simple imageView:

```
    byte[] bookImage = books.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bookImage, 0, bookImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now I'm trying to use the Picasso library to prevent a 'Out Of Memory' crash.
This is the code:

```
Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(bitmap).into(holder.imageView);
```

Unfortunately i cannot use load(bitmap). How can i use the Picasso library correctly for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Glide for this:

```
Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(bookImage).asBitmap().into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Glad to help you ;)